# Is it possible to disable 'Install gatsby-starter' on Chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app, gatsby

We released a static website using gatsby. We just noticed that user will see 'Install gatsby-starter' on Chrome browser setting.

Why is it appearing on?  Can we disable it?

gatsby version:  "^2.13.39"

[image: Screen Shot 2019-11-28 at 12 41 51]

Answer (score 0):

The answer I got from Gatsby team.
"
This is Chrome supporting PWAs in the browser itself. If you open your site with an Android Phone you'll also see a prompt to install it. You can remove this functionality by removing the manifest (+ optionally offline) plugin:
"